# Warning when using Reachability.h

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When using `Reachability.h` — Apple's code to deal with connections on iOS:

```
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
Declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in' will not be visible outside of this function
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `#import <netinet/in.h>` in Reachability.h file and this warning will be gone.. :D

Comment: That didn't work.  The warning disappeared for the lite version of my app but not the standard version target.

Comment: clean and build your targets again..